# Не работает кик в боте discord python

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я сделал один код для бота Discord, чтобы при команде `jb!kick [@user] [причина]` упоминаемого кикало с сервера.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "jb!") 

@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
 await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
 member_id = member.id
 member: Member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)
 await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
```

Но когда я активирую эту команду, то пишется сообщение об изгнании, но участник не кикается. В консоли тем временем происходит это:

```
Ignoring exception in command kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/give2.py", line 38, in kick
    await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kick'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kick'
```

*Да-да. Я делаю это через termux. Но я тестировал до этого код на компьютере и там примерно та же ситуация.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вы заново пытаетесь получить участника сервера?

Здесь должно быть достаточно этих строк

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "jb!") 

@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
 await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
 await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} was kicked from the server.')
    log(f"{member} kicked {ctx.message.author}")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]